# Update Windows 8 Enterprise to Windows 8.1 Enterprise KMS activation

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, windows-8.1

So it is shown that volume license packages of Windows 8, like Pro and Enterprise, are unavailable for upgrading.

I received a link last night to download the Windows 8.1 Enterprise 90-day Evaluation, but it will replace my current Windows 8 Enterprise version.

Is it known when these versions will become available for upgrade? I've been waiting patiently for weeks to get this upgrade.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to do the upgrade, change the key, then activate like you normally do.

Comment: Questions about release date are considered off-topic as they are mostly conjecture or opinion. Unless this is published somewhere, nobody is going to know.

Answer (score 1):

For businesses who acquired Windows 8 Enterprise through Software Assurance for Windows on a volume license agreement, the option to update through the Windows Store is not available. Administrators will find the Windows 8.1 Enterprise installation media at the Volume Licensing Service Center. Windows 8.1 can be deployed to Windows 8 computers using a software distribution tool such as System Center Configuration Manager (run setup.exe /auto:upgrade)

Comment: If you describe the process and the gotchas I will upvote this question